# How to make the button disable before ticking the checkbox in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Intro = () => {
    return (
        <section className="landing1">
        <div className="orange-overlay">
          <div className="landing-inner">
            <h1 className="large">
               A fasciniting experience awaits you.
            </h1>
            <h2>
                But before you get started, here are a few points to keep in mind.
            </h2>
            <p>You have 10 minutes to complete all the challenges</p>
            <p>For a better gaming experience, we would recommend a desktop web browser</p>
            <p>Desert Survival is a click and play experience</p>
            <p>Only the score of your first try will be considered, however, you can attempt the experience as many times as you wish</p>
            <p>If you chose to leave the game midway, your progress resets and you will have to start from the beginning</p>
            <p>Make sure your audio is always turn on for maximum effect</p>
            <p>Everything you need is already in the room and just needs to be discovered</p>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="tick" onChange={() => document.getElementById('terms').disabled} />
            <p > I've read the rules</p>
            <Button name="terms" id="terms" disabled >Receive</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
    );
  };

  export default Intro;
```

Comment: You need to add the code in the appropriate `style`. It is also better to provide a jsfiddle. Also provide more information regarding your question.

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working?  At a glance it looks like you're not doing this "the React way".  Instead of trying to make the checkbox change the button, track the button state in a React state value (with the `useState` hook).  In this case a simple boolean state will work.  The checkbox updates the state, and the button's `disabled` attribute is driven by that state.

Answer (score 0):

as some of the comments mentioned, it seems like you are not doing this the React way. I've made a quick modification using `useState` to handle the state and change it accordingly. Take a look:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Intro = () => {
  const [hasChecked, setHasChecked] = useState(false)

  return (
    <section className="landing1">
      <div className="orange-overlay">
        <div className="landing-inner">
          <h1 className="large">A fasciniting experience awaits you.</h1>
          <h2>But before you get started, here are a few points to keep in mind.</h2>
          <p>You have 10 minutes to complete all the challenges</p>
          <p>For a better gaming experience, we would recommend a desktop web browser</p>
          <p>Desert Survival is a click and play experience</p>
          <p>
            Only the score of your first try will be considered, however, you can attempt the
            experience as many times as you wish
          </p>
          <p>
            If you chose to leave the game midway, your progress resets and you will have to start
            from the beginning
          </p>
          <p>Make sure your audio is always turn on for maximum effect</p>
          <p>Everything you need is already in the room and just needs to be discovered</p>
          <input type="checkbox" id="tick" onChange={() => setHasChecked((checked) => !checked)} />
          <p> I've read the rules</p>
          <Button name="terms" id="terms" disabled={!hasChecked}>
            Receive
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Intro
```

I am using `hasChecked` as state management which will be `true` or `false` depending on wether there was any change to the checkbox, initially, it is set to `false` (`useState(false)`). the `disabled={!hasChecked}` means it will set the disabled property of the button to be true, if `hasChecked` value is false

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,  { useState} from 'react'

const Intro = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState('')
    return (
        <section className="landing1">
        <div className="orange-overlay">
          <div className="landing-inner">
            <h1 className="large">
               A fasciniting experience awaits you.
            </h1>
            <h2>
                But before you get started, here are a few points to keep in mind.
            </h2>
            <p>You have 10 minutes to complete all the challenges</p>
            <p>For a better gaming experience, we would recommend a desktop web browser</p>
            <p>Desert Survival is a click and play experience</p>
            <p>Only the score of your first try will be considered, however, you can attempt the experience as many times as you wish</p>
            <p>If you chose to leave the game midway, your progress resets and you will have to start from the beginning</p>
            <p>Make sure your audio is always turn on for maximum effect</p>
            <p>Everything you need is already in the room and just needs to be discovered</p>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked={checked} id="tick" onChange={() => setChecked(!checked) } />
            <p > I've read the rules</p>
            <button name="terms" id="terms" disabled={checked} >Receive</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
    );
  };

  export default Intro;
```